# How can I use my Samsung Pen in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: hardware, notes

I'm using Samsung NT950QAA-X58A and I installed ubuntu on my labtop.

This model includes s pen so I want to use it. But My ubuntu detect this as mouse.

Is able to make my ubuntu detect my pen as pen(not mouse)?

And can u recommend me some note apps which is able to write something via my pen(like onenote, samsung notes in Windows)?

**EDIT**

I installed ubuntu desktop version with minimal installation(which not includes libera office, etc.) and my desktop env is GNOME.

I don't know what is GA and HWE but I installed least version of my ubuntu 18.04 in 1 weeks ago(My computer fails installing ubuntu 20.04 so I installed previos version of that).

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Ubuntu 18.04 you installed (desktop? server?) and likely more important which kernel stack you opted for (GA or HWE; installation media controls which is default but you didn't say; though you can also select at install time for some server installations). I don't know your device, but if your pen is recognized as a mouse, you can use it in any drawing program (it's easier in my opinion drawing with a pen compared with a mouse).

Comment: What's the difference between a "pen" and a "mouse"? Both are pointing devices, both have clickable buttons. Any drawing app supports mouse, so it should support pen.

Comment: 18.04 & 18.04.1 media default to the GA kernel, 18.04.2 and later media (for desktop) default to the HWE kernel.... so the media used to install Ubuntu 18.04 tells us which you're using (assuming you didn't change it... if you don't understand it you're unlikely to have changed it). But you haven't said which 18.04 media you installed, if desktop, if server, which desktop or server ISO (ie. 18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, 18.04.3 etc)   What do you mean by "*least version of Ubuntu*"?

Comment: I installed desktop 18.04.5